# Discord.py giveaway command random choice from reactions error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a giveaway command for my Discord.py bot. I used an guide from YouTube: https://youtu.be/s531M7jLh6A but it gets an error on `winner = random.choice(users) part:`

Full command:

```
@bot.command()
 @commands.has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
 async def gstart(ctx, mins : int, *, prize:str):
     embed=discord.Embed(color=0x0f84eb)
     embed.add_field(name="Giveaway!", value=f"{prize}", inline=False)
     end = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds = mins*60)
     embed.add_field(name="Kończy się:", value= f"{end} UTC")
     embed.set_footer(text="<> and hosted with ♡ by Maciejka")
     my_msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
     await my_msg.add_reaction('✋')
     await asyncio.sleep(10)
     new_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(my_msg.id)
     users = new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
     users.pop(users.index(bot.user))
     print('1')
     winner = random.choice(users)
     print('3')
     await ctx.send(f"Congrats! {winner} won {prize}!")
```

Full error i got:

```
/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py:88: RuntimeWarning: coroutine '_AsyncIterator.flatten' was never awaited
  self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one line that you forgot to await. As seen in the error. If you can't figure that out from the error, you might wanna look at a few tutorials. Thanks. :)

Comment: Yeah, i know i didn't await this, but random.*something* don't needs to be awaited, and after awaiting this it still got's the error.